# ¿Cómo podemos evitar muchos versiones en nuestro app?

Tags: java

No sé si estoy rompiendo la política de stackoverflow por pediendo este tipo de pregunta o no?

En nuestra aplicación JEE, tenemos algunas fórmulas matemáticas (para algunos cálculos útiles) hardcoded, el reto es que si queremos agregar nuevas fórmulas que requieren una nueva versión y queremos evitar esto con copiamos esta fórmula en la tabla SQL, entonces la usaremos en nuestra app para el cálculo.

¿Podría decirme si esta una buena idea o no?

Comment: Pon un ejemplo más ilustrativo, aunque sea seudocodigo. No entiendo bien lo que quieres

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez (lo siento no estoy bien en espanol) me voy a Explicar más cuál es nuestro reto, las fórmulas dependen de (por ejemplo, f1 = a + b + c) a, b, c pueden estar en Data Base o en UI (input text). el usuario puede agregar otras furmulas f2 = a * b-c + d sin hardcoded

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión seria una de las mejores formas ,no obstante tendrías que tener en cuenta que lo único que podrás cambiar sera la formula matemática,es decir si lo que quieres es cambiar formula por otra en vez de cambiar la misma formula tendrás que hacerlo de otra forma. 
Te pongo un ejemplo porque se que me explico muy mal:
Imagina que tienes dos formulas una la llamamos Sumar(a+b+c+e) y otra Restar(a-b-c-e), si lo que quieres es cambiar el procedimiento que se sigue dentro de Sumar por ejemplo Sumar=(a+b) la forma que propones seria la correcta,no obstante si lo que quieres es que en vez de Sumar lo que haga sea Restar tendrás que buscar otra forma,te dejo un link de un foro donde se habla de este tema: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/ae715779-355b-483f-b190-676942cbde10/como-puedo-crear-una-formula-de-operaciones-matematicas-y-luego-almacenar-en-una-bd-para-un-uso?forum=vbes